# useReducer React approach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm playing with `useReducer` react's api, and wonder to know the difference between the theoretical (documentation) part and one I implement.

**intialState of commponent with useReducer hook:**

```
const [fields, dispatch] = React.useReducer(formReducer, {
        firstName: { value: '', isValid: false },
        lastName: { value: '', isValid: false },
    });
```

**theoretical Variant**

```
 const formActionTypes = {
    firstName: 'FIRST_NAME',
    lastName: 'LAST_NAME',
};
....
function formReducer(state, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
    case formActionTypes.firstName:
        return { ...state, firstName: { ...action.payload } };
    case formActionTypes.lastName:
        return { ...state, lastName: { ...action.payload } };
    default:
        return state;
}
}
....
dispatch({
            type: formActionTypes[name], //name is input name
            payload: { value, isValid } //value is e.target.value
        });
```

**MY implimentation**

```
function formReducer(state, action) {
    return { ...state, [action.name]: { ...action.payload } };
}
 ....
    dispatch({
                name, //name is input name
                payload: { value, isValid } //value is e.target.value
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

The two reducers you've shown will both work and produce identical results if that's what you're asking. I think the theoretical version version you're getting from the documentation is meant to demonstrate a particular concept, though, which your reducer arguably violates (though it's not a big deal; our job is to make working code, not to pass some purity test!).

Specifically, you typically want to somewhat *decouple* actions from state. The action shouldn't just be a mirror of your state data structure; if you want that coupling, you'd might as well use `useState` instead and just set the state directly. A reducer is meant to decouple this by you modeling a description of the action, and then it's only the reducer that decides how that action acts on state. You might, for example, decide to add a clear form button. With your current pattern, you'd have to dispatch two actions, which would cause two state updates, because your actions closely model the state. The switch statement pattern allows you to easily apply different types of logic based on different types of actions.

There are no wrong answers, just different approaches all with their merits. Here's one that I think introduces better decoupling by letting the reducer logic take care of knowing about whether a field is valid:

```
const SET_FIRST_NAME = Symbol();
const SET_LAST_NAME = Symbol();
const CLEAR_FORM = Symbol();

// Call action creators instead, like: dispatch(setFirstName(e.target.value));
const setFirstName = name => { type: SET_FIRST_NAME, value: name };
const setLastName = name => { type: SET_LAST_NAME, value: name };
const clearForm = () => { type: CLEAR_FORM };

const initialState = {
  firstName: { value: '', isValid: false },
  lastName: { value: '', isValid: false }
};

const notEmpty = value => !!(value && value.trim().length);

const validateFirstName = notEmpty; // Or replace with different logic
const validateLastName = notEmpty;

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_FIRST_NAME:
      return { 
        ...state, 
        firstName: {
          value: action.value, 
          isValid: validateFirstName(value) 
        } 
      }
    case SET_LAST_NAME:
      return { 
        ...state, 
        lastName: {
          value: action.value, 
          isValid: validateLastName(value) 
        } 
      }
    case CLEAR_FORM:
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: I aggree, the same I need to submit for instance, separate action. Sure better to isolate all bussines logic of component and use useReducer and action to be sure that only action responsible for this flow.